# NO ME IDENTIFICA INCLUDE EN PHP

Tags: php, html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se porque en ese archivo cuando intento usar include con php aparece en blanco, no es el codigo porque lo probe en otro archivo y funciona, pero en ese archivo no me lo identifica

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sigue sin arreglarse, aparece en blanco

Comment: Lo puse bien y aun asi no funciona, probe la misma linea de codigos en otro archivo y funciona bien pero en ese archivo no

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, tu código debe estar como texto en lugar de imagen, por favor edita la pregunta.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrarnos el código completo de ese archivo?

Answer (score 0):

Puede que el error sea no cerrar el include, te recomiendo que lo pongas de la siguiente forma:

```
include 'registrar.php';
```

También te recomiendo dejar los includes en la parte de arriba.